# Go executing simple script - not entering for loop

Tags: loops, go

I am facing an issue when trying to execute a simple script that iterates over a file line by line and writes parts of its contents to a new file each:

```
 func main() {
    inFile := "file.tsv"

    reader, err := os.Open(inFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer reader.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
    scanner.Scan()  // skip header

    for scanner.Scan() {
        row := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), "\t")

        outFileName := fmt.Sprintf("./out_name__%s", row[1])
        writer, err := os.Create(outFileName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            writer.Close()
        }

        writer.Write([]byte(row[2]))
        writer.Close()
    }
}
```

When I `go run script.go` this file - Go just doesn't enter the loop? The script exits after skipping the header. I cannot see any `goroutine`-like background thread that doesn't get waited on.

Can you explain to me why this happens?

Comment: semantics: as a compiled language go code cannot accurately be called a "script".   library: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/miku/span/encoding/tsv might be useful to you.  invocation: `go run <filename>` is not recommended.  if you insist on using `go run` instead of `go build`, `go run .` at least will include all the stuff that `go build` will build.  question: what does your input data look like?

Comment: also, make sure your example code compiles and illustrates the problem before you post it. that code has a syntax error on `writer.Write([]byte(row[2))` which means either you haven't actually run it or you haven't faithfully represented what you did run here.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/pfrCb1jgHwe a simplified version works fine.  Check your input data.

Comment: @erik258 fixed the syntax error, reason: I replace a few chars in `row[2]` and use a surrogate var to hold the replaced string, which is then passed to the `writer.Write` function. No logic change, my code compiles and does what it is supposed to when *hardcoding* calls to `scanner.Scan()`.

Comment: I am aware Go is not a script language, yet this is nothing more than a script judging by content and usage. My input data is as fine as it has to be since, again, when hardcoding calls to `scanner.Scan()` with the subsequent string manipulation and writing out to file, this script works perfectly fine. Using a subset of the file, no matter the size and also only including lines that work with the hardcoding way, doesn't change behaviour. `go build` + exec does not change the behavor.

Comment: Adding up to *no logic change* - running the *exact* code above exhibits the exact same behavior outlined in the question and my comments. tsv library is not useful to me.

Comment: It seems to work after I made the script do something with a dummy array that fills up during the loop, after the loop.

Comment: After the loop, check the return value of scanner.Err(). Also check that after the first Scan Text() returns the header as expected and not more (which would indicate an issues with line endings, for example).